# XML text transformation

Tags: regex, xml, awk

I have a large file part of which is like below:

```
<DataGroup xsi:type="ReportDataGroup">
<SmartReportTemplate DescriptionContentType="text/plain"
IsActive="true">
<Name ns1:translate="yes">Agent Summary</Name>
<Defaults type="defaults">
<Title ns1:translate="yes">Agent Summary Report</Title>
<Description ns1:translate="yes"></Description>
```

Now I need to check for the patterns `.*ns1:translate="yes">(.*)</.*`
and when found I need to add string from the array below this line.
Along with the string from the array I need to add the tags `<Name
xml:lang="ja">` and `</Name>` around the string obt from the array if the
line above has `</Name>` and need to add `<Title xml:lang="ja">` and
`</Title>` tags if the pattern matched line has `</Title>`

The final output should look like:

```
<DataGroup xsi:type="ReportDataGroup">
<SmartReportTemplate DescriptionContentType="text/plain"
IsActive="true">
<Name ns1:translate="yes">EM - perc</Name>
<Name xml:lang="ja">\u886815wEM - perce ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u5834</Name>
<Defaults type="defaults">
<Title ns1:translate="yes">AG - Rep</Title>
<Title xml:lang="ja">\u886815wAG - Rep ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u5834</Title>
<Description ns1:translate="yes"></Description>
```

where the strings "`\u886815wEM - perce ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~ ~~\u5834`" etc ... are there in an array.

Any idea how to script this? I tried with sed inside a while loop that reads file line by line but it takes a very long time. I tried with awk but I am not able to access the special character array inside awk.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454 before anyone gets angry with you for wanting to modify XML through regular expressions :-)

Comment: How are array contents mapped to replacements? Sequentially (i.e. one array item per match, counting upwards?).

Comment: @DanielAndersson: humourous value of the linked answer apart, there are situations where a regex can be enough – especially [as regular expressions are perfectly able to *match* (albeit not *parse*) well-formed XML](http://nikic.github.com/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html). It’s all the difference between a robust architecture for this kind of task and a quick hack. As long as you are aware that a hack is just that (at best brittle and at worst erratic), it might be the easier solution to pull a a quick one, compared to, say, XSLT or custom XML processing in a script.

Answer (score 0):

If a partial solution in `vim` is acceptable:

```
:%s/\(.*\(Name\|Title\).*ns1:translate="yes">.*<\/.*\)/<\2 xml:lang="ja">\\u886815wEM - perce \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~ \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~ \~\~\\u5834<\/\2>\r\1/g
```

escaping `\` by `\/` and `~` by `\~`.

`\(Name\|Title\)` allows matching two patterns and recalling them with `\2` here.